# Mongodb - Update property per object in array of object, Insert if doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wish to update a property per object in array of objects, but if some of the objects doesn't exists, insert the object instead.

Currently I used "upsert", which creates a new document when no document matches the query, unfortunately it is replacing a single item with my entire list.

Worth to mention that I am using mongoist to perform an async requests.

My code:

```
    this.tokenArray = [
 { token: "654364543" },
 { token: "765478656" },
 { token: "876584432" },
 { token: "125452346" },
 { token: "874698557" },
 { token: "654364543" }
 ]

 database.upsertDatebaseItem(this.tokenArray.map(x => { return x.token }), { valid : true }, 'Tokens');


 async upsertDatebaseItem(itemKey, itemValue, collectionName) {
    try {
        await this.database[collectionName].update({ token : { $in: itemKey}}, { $set: itemValue }, {upsert : true} , {multi : true});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`An error occurred while attempting to update ${itemType} to the database: ${error}`);
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do it:

```
const bulkUpdate = this.tokenArray.map((x) => {
            return {
                "updateOne": {
                    "filter": { "token": x.token },
                    "update": { "$set": { "valid": true } },
                    "upsert": true
                }
            };
        });
```

and:

```
this.database[collectionName].bulkWrite(bulkUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

To upsert with mongoist, use the following:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp()
for(var doc of docs) bulk.find( { _id: doc._id } ).upsert().updateOne(doc); // or use replaceOne()
await bulk.execute();
```

Converted to your case that would be

```js
var bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp()
for(var tokenItem of tokenArray) bulk.find( { token : tokenItem.token } ).upsert().updateOne(tokenItem); // or use replaceOne()
await bulk.execute();
```